# Serialize objects with Play Scala api and Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, jackson, playframework-json

I try to serialize my models in a play 2.0 application with Scala to Json. This is how my code looks like:

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Task(id: Long, label: String, date: String)

object Task {

  ...

  implicit object TaskFormat extends Format[Task] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Task = Task(
      (json \ "id").as[Long],
      (json \ "label").as[String],
      (json \ "date").as[String])

    def writes(t: Task): JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(t.id),
      "label" -> JsString(t.label),
      "date" -> JsString(t.date)))
  }
}
```

Unfortunartly I get the following error when running the application:

```
verriding method reads in trait Reads of type (json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.Task]; method reads has incompatible type
```

I didn't yet find a solution. The documentation of the api (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/libs/json/package.html) seems to suggest the approach I've taken as well.

Does anybody spot my mistake?

Many thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is: the return type must be

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.Task]
```

So it looks to me like you are returning the `Task` directly, not wrapping it in a `JsResult`.

I don't use Play, but this is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

So, given that, what is the issue?  If you look at the Play 2.0 documentation, it says `reads` returns a `T`.  But if you look at [the GitHub source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/dd287081fbd2206d4d809c2de8d8a29ec0d138a4/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala) you find that it was changed to `JsResult[T]` as of August 21, 2012.

So you're using a newer version than the one people have written advice for.

I'm not sure whether the newer API is online, but you can browse the JSON source [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json).

Comment: Okay, maybe I really don't see it right now, but that doesn't help me much. I get what the compiler tells me, but I don't know how to return a `JsResult[Task]`. All the documentation on the web also seems to have the same code as I do (e.g. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaJsonGenerics, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979638/serializing-objects-to-json-with-play-api-libs-json).

Comment: @jomikr - Edited my answer, as I figured out what was going on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not imagine that they changed the api in such a way. Looking at the sources finally got me the solution: `def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(Task(
      (json \ "id").as[Long],
      (json \ "label").as[String],
      (json \ "date").as[String]))`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/) post, a more correct way to implement Reads[T] in Play 2.1 would be:

```
implicit val productReads: Reads[Product] = (
    (__ \ "ean").read[Long] and
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "description").read[String]
)(Product.apply _)
```

And don't forget additional imports:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._ 
import play.api.libs.json._
```